# Check if URL is in a sentence with regex

Tags: regex, go

I need to check if a URLs is in a sentence.

```
Some text. This is good. 
https://stackoverflow.com
More text
```

`More text https://stackoverflow.com. More text. This is bad`

I can find the URLs after some research, but I'm stuck on finding them in sentences.

https://regex101.com/r/AmuFIX/5

```
((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)[\r\n]
```

Comment: Tried removing `[\r\n]`? BTW, it won't match `http://стопкоронавирус.рф`

Comment: Fixed the ask, since it didn't encompass what I was looking for.

Comment: So, remove `[\r\n]`.

Comment: I did, it doesn't work.it just finds all URLs. I only want those in a sentence.

Comment: Do you mean when it is not the only text on an individual line?

Comment: Correct. If URL is surrounded by other text that's bad.

Comment: Ok, I suggest splitting the text into lines, skip those that fully match your `^URL_REGEX$` pattern, and then extract URLs from the rest of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you're looking for cases where a URL is mixed with other text on a *line*, not necessarily a *sentence*. For that, I would use something like this:

```
.+\b((http|ftp|https):\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)\b.+
```

This changes your query by asserting that there must be some characters, followed by a word boundary, followed by a URL, followed by a word boundary, followed by some other characters. This won't match a URL at the start or end of a line that also has other content; for that you'd likely need to two two separate matches - one for a URL with something before it, one for a URL with something after it.

Comment: It won't work because OP also wants to get URLs *NOT* starting with `http`, `https` or `ftp`, see `((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?` in the original pattern.

Comment: I want them with http, https and ftp. The original regex does pull all URLs that start with those patterns.

Comment: Without a schema it is not a URL, it is just a domain, and domains are almost impossible to detect. Consider that, for example, `localhost` is a valid domain; `google.com` is a domain, `google.exe` is a filename; `world.Hello` is normal text with a typo (missing space); etc. Without the schema you're going to get a ton of false negatives in any broad corpus of text.